# How to Import sklearn?

Tags: scikit-learn, pycharm

I have installed Sklearn 0.0 using pip3 and installed Scikit-learn 0.22, when i going to (import sklear) or (from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split) i receive the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/khaled.abdalla/PycharmProjects/Py_Project1/RegressionAnalysis.py", line 6, in <module>
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
  File "C:\Users\khaled.abdalla\PycharmProjects\Py_Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 76, in <module>
    from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
  File "C:\Users\khaled.abdalla\PycharmProjects\Py_Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_show_versions.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._openmp_helpers import _openmp_parallelism_enabled
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Which base interpreter did you use to create `C:\Users\khaled.abdalla\PycharmProjects\Py_Project1\venv`? Was it Anaconda by any chance?

Comment: This packaging issue is being tracked at: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/15899

In the mean time you can install scikt-learn from conda-forge:

`conda install conda-forge::scikit-learn`

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that you should not run `pip3 install sklearn` but `pip3 install scikit-learn` instead. `sklearn` is an alias and should not be used. You can refer to the documentation to install scikit-learn there: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html

To remove the alias package use `pip3 uninstall sklearn`.

Comment: So it could be linked with missing OpenMP and we think that a quick fix will be to install VC++ (2015, 2017, 2019): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads. Select the architecture of your system (32 bits -> x86; 64 bits -> x64)

Answer (score -2):

You have to install also the Numpy and Scipy packages.
Use the unofficial installers from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: I already installed the Numpy and Scipy packages using pip3 install ...

Comment: I had imagined it. But with Windows nothing is easy. Use that link..